# Depiction of the Menorah, the *Shulchan* and *Kadosh HaKadoshim* on ancient coins?

Tags: history, money, avodah-zarah, menorah--in-temple

On some rare ancient coins of Matityah Antigonus, there are depictions of what seem to be the Menorah and the *Shulchan* (one obverse die even seems to show the *Lechem HaPanim*).
This coin has an inscription in Greek and [sometimes] Hebrew (מתתיה כהן גדול).

See: http://menorahcoinproject.com/atge.htm

Also, Bar-Kochba minted several Sela'im that have the *Kadosh HaKadoshim* on the obverse:

[image: Bar-Kochba Sela]

(The above coin has the obverse inscrption of "שמעון" and reverse legend of "ש[נת] ב לח[רת] ישראל" around a lulav and etrog)

How were Antigonus and Bar-Kochba able to mint coins with these images on them?
It says in Avodah Zarah 43a:

> A man may not make a . . . menorah like the design of the Menorah. He
> may, however, make one with five, six or eight [branches], but with
> seven he may not make it even though it might be of other metals. Rebi
> Yosi bar Yehudah says, "Also of wood he may not make it because that
> is how the Chashmonaim made it." They said to him, "Is that a proof?
> It consisted of metal staves overlaid with tin. When they became
> richer they made one of silver, and when they became even richer they
> made one of gold!

Does this not forbid creating images and designs of *menorot*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Rashi* on that *g'mara* clearly says (about the first prohibition) that it means making a life-size model, which would mean pictures on coins are okay. Likewise, it's codified in [the *Rambam*](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=8&hilchos=41&perek=7&halocha=10) as "one may not make a house of the form of the *hechal*, a porch of the form of the *ulam*,… a candelabrum of the form of the *m'nora*", etc., and [*Shulchan Aruch*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&pgnum=128) writes much the same (if anything, more clearly): depictions would seem to be fine.